# How to position an NSView below another NSView?

Tags: swift, nsview

Good day,

Who has an idea on how to position an NSButton below another view in its superview?

Here is the code I've written but the position of the NSButton doesn't change regardless of where the NSView is. I would appreciate if someone could look into this and help me solve it.

```
 @objc func printHello() {
        var theButton = NSButton(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 168, height: 32))
        theButton.bezelStyle = .rounded
        theButton.controlSize = .large
        theButton.keyEquivalent = "\r"
        theButton.title = "Edit Chart Data"
        self.superview?.addSubview(theButton, positioned: .below, relativeTo: self)
        print(self.frame)
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `addSubview(theButton, positioned: .below, relativeTo: self)` does not define frame position of an item. The "positioned: .below" part is actually meant for Z coordinate.

So what you did was told the view to add a subview below "self" in its hierarchy. It means that if frames of `self` and the button would overlap, then `self` would be in front of the button. Using `.above` would put the button in front.

You can use either frame property to achieve your goal or constraints. With frame it should be something like

```
func placeView(_ targetView: NSView, belowView currentView: NSView) {
    targetView.frame = NSRect(x: currentView.frame.minX,
                              y: currentView.frame.minY-currentView.frame.height,
                              width: currentView.frame.width,
                              height: currentView.frame.height)
}
```

Using it like:

```
self.superview?.addSubview({
    let theButton = NSButton(frame: .zero)
    placeView(theButton, belowView: self)
    theButton.bezelStyle = .rounded
    theButton.controlSize = .large
    theButton.keyEquivalent = "\r"
    theButton.title = "New view"
    return theButton
}())
```

When using constraints something like this may be done:

```
func placeView(_ targetView: NSView, belowView currentView: NSView) {
    let view = targetView.superview!
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: currentView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: targetView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: currentView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: targetView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: currentView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: targetView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: currentView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: currentView.frame.height))
}
```

And using it like:

```
let theButton: NSButton = {
    let theButton = NSButton(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 90.0))
    theButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    theButton.bezelStyle = .rounded
    theButton.controlSize = .large
    theButton.keyEquivalent = "\r"
    theButton.title = "New view"
    return theButton
}()
self.view.addSubview(theButton)
placeView(theButton, belowView: someView)
self.view.layoutSubtreeIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Thank you, but its adding it a ways on top of the view not below

Comment: @Matthew1998 which of the two methods did you use? In any case it should be very intuitive how to correct this...

Comment: the first one bro, the one without constraints